# Exclude column from calculation and then retrieve it again

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df (ndv19) with n number of columns. I need to exclude column named 'Id'(position = 1) from a calculation I need to perform (other columns names are dates such as 20161025), and once calculation is done, retrieve again the previously excluded column 'Id' respecting its former position.
I tried with iloc and drop, I succeed to exclude, but I dont know how to retrieve afterwards...
Thanks in advance!!

succeded to exclude with this = rep19.ix[:,~rep19.columns.str.contains('^I')]
and this rep19.iloc[:,1:,]

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the data and columns look like as well as the calculations you are running? If you don't do something that changes the number of rows then it is very easy to remove and add a row

Comment: Get the column list without 'id' column name using: `test_cols = df.columns.difference(['id'])`. Then apply operations on these columns using `df[test_cols]`

Comment: Hi, please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
temp_df = ndv19['Id']
ndv19 = ndv19.drop(['Id'], axis=1)
# Do the calculations
ndv19['Id'] = temp_df
```

Comment: Ok, that worked but is a little difficult to reproduce it through several df 
 ---  temp_rep19=rep19['Id'] ---
---rep19 = rep19.drop(['Id'], axis=1)---
---rep19= (rep19 -706.653564453125)/(732.274322509766-706.653564453125)---
---rep19['Id']=temp_rep19---

Comment: 'Id' column appears now in last position, while at the beggining was in position 1. Anyways is working now, so thank you very much!

Comment: You could try this to reorder rep19=rep19[['Id','Col2','Col3','Col4']]